# Windows 10 Enterprise systems disobeying lock screen background GPO

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

The following GPO is configured at the domain level for our systems:

- Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative
  Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > "Force a specific
  default lock screen and logon image"

Systems that are freshly imaged have no problem displaying the lock screen specified by the GPO. However, some systems which have received an in-place upgrade to Windows 10 20H2 had their branding broken, such that they no longer obey the GPO. If we enable the GPO allowing user specified lock screen backgrounds to test, we can manually specify the JPG, confirming it *can* work. GPUPDATE has no effect. The path to the image is local to the system as part of the image, and not a UNC path. Testing with alternative image files at alternate locations has no effect on the problem systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please validate the Windows 10 SKU you apply this setting to, maybe the upgrade process broke something, as this setting only applies to Enterprise, Education, and Server SKUs.

[Reference](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.ControlPanelDisplay::CPL_Personalization_ForceDefaultLockScreen)